# how to use in condition in yii

Tags: mysql, yii

I am facing this problem that how to use in conditon in yii.
I want to make a CListView in a tab which the tab number not at first.
How can I do ajax pagination on CListView, so I don't get the page refreshing but only the CListView instead ?

Answer (score 0):

Call this in javascript: $.fn.yiiListView.update('id-of-your-listview');

the same for grid view: $.fn.yiiGridView.update